# How to get the Email Address knowing the Subscriber ID?

Tags: marketing-cloud

We use Event Notification Service to get notified in near real-time of clicks inside our emails.

Our external Webhook receives notifications of that type on every click :

```
[
    {
         eventCategoryType: 'EngagementEvents.EmailClick',
         ...
         channel: 'email',
         ...
         composite: {
             ...
             subscriberId: 'subscriberId here'
         },
         info: {
             contentLink: 'clicked URL here',
             ...
         }
    }
]
```

We get the clicked URL, which we are interested in, but we wish to get the recipient Email as well.

So far, we looked closely at the API, but we couldn't find a way to retrieve email from the system key Subscriber Id.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure this a best practice, but you can do the following :

1. Add an extra parameter to your URL in your email. Like `https://your-link/?mail=%%emailaddr%%&other=val`
2. You will receive a notification containing `info.contentLink : https://your-link/?mail=mail@youarelooking.for&other=val`
3. Get the url parameter : you have the email

No need for a retrieval from subscriber id.

Comment: I personally discourage people from placing PII in urls. This is a.o. due to this being exposed and generally accessible to any 1st or 3rd party script running on the website.

Comment: @LukasLunow safe advice. The email address can be hashed, stored in MC and this hash can be passed as a parameter. Then, a call to the API with the hash as a find parameter should be able to give the original address.

Comment: The real question here imho is the complete use-case, which is likely to be solved more simply.

Answer (score -1):

Query system Data Views and call your endpoint from Automation Studio.

Not a real time solution, but no sensitive information exposed.